# Разделенная строка не находится внутри диапазона ключей региона splitKey

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть не так. Я использую java и hbase, пытаюсь разделить таблицу на регионы и сталкиваюсь с проблемой:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: Split row is not inside region key range splitKey:101640973600000 region: {ENCODED => df01c31740b178827b32de6e99aa921b, NAME => 'TableRs,91640973600000,1651242448761.df01c31740b178827b32de6e99aa921b.', STARTKEY => '91640973600000', ENDKEY => ''}
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.assignment.SplitTableRegionProcedure.checkSplittable(SplitTableRegionProcedure.java:214)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.assignment.SplitTableRegionProcedure.<init>(SplitTableRegionProcedure.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.assignment.AssignmentManager.createSplitProcedure(AssignmentManager.java:747)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$3.run(HMaster.java:1863)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.MasterProcedureUtil.submitProcedure(MasterProcedureUtil.java:134)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.splitRegion(HMaster.java:1855)
```

Я не понимаю почему ключ 101640973600000 выходит за рамки ENDKEY => ''. Помогите, пожалуйста!
Возможно дело в value=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00&, но как и что нужно исправить

```
hbase(main):002:0> scan 'hbase:meta',{FILTER=>"PrefixFilter('TableRs')"}
...
TableRs,91640973600 column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1651640953917, value={ENCODED => df01c31740b178827b32de6e99aa921b, NAME => 'TableRs,91640973600000,1651242448761.df01c31740b178827b32de6e99aa921b.', STARTKEY => '91640973600000', ENDKEY => ''}
column=info:seqnumDuringOpen, timestamp=1651640953917, value=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00&
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в другом месте, мой массив байтов был не отсотртирован и вызывался в порядке создания, а не возрастания, собственно после сортировки массива splitKey создается без проблем.